# Eclipse Sign-In for Android не запускается активность для входа

Tags: java, android, eclipse

При запуске приложения в Eclipse инициализируется GoogleSignInClient:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build(); 
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

далее в обработчике нажатия кнопки пытаюсь подключиться

```
Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(); 

startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Сперва оно ругалось что в манифесте не объявлена активность. Добавил, как он просил в манифест активность, которой ему не хватало, с таким именем:

android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"

Теперь после нажатия кнопки вообще ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите метод **onActivityResult** и добавьте следующий код:

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
  Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
  handleSignInResult(task);
  return;
}
```

Comment: onActivityResult отработал, и дальше в handleSignInResult при вызове GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class); вылетает исключение ApiException.getStatusCode() = 12500. Я предполагал что должна открыться активность, где я подключусь к учетке гугла,а оно сразу в result переходит

Comment: а вы на эмуляторе запускаете приложение?

Comment: Попробуйте обновить Google Play сервисы http://geek-nose.com/kak-obnovit-servisy-google-play/#dlya-chego-nuzhny-servisy-google-play

Comment: запускаю на эмуляторе

Comment: обновите тогда сервисы, должно помочь